# Angular Router ignores URL, when using custom ngDoBootstrap and createCustomElement

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-router, custom-element

**WHEN** I use custom `ngDoBootstrap` function instead of default `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  exports: [ AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ AppComponent ],
  // bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  public ngDoBootstrap(): any {
    const appElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('my-app', appElement);
  }
}
```

**THEN** 
Application routing is broken.

It ignores any changes in the URL and only works when I click on  `<a [routerLink]='...'>`. Also the initial route / is not loaded.

It must be caused by the custom bootstrap mechanizm, because when I uncomment the `bootstrap: [AppComponent]`, everything works fine.

Full code is available here: [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customelements-routing?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) (needs to be downloaded and run locally because of typescript version used by stackblitz)

How to make the routing work with custom app module bootstrapping?

Comment: I added a polyfill to make it work on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customelements-routing-ts7dyc. What do you mean by "initial route / is not loaded"? It redirects to `#/hello`, as defined in the routing

Comment: @David: First of all, it should automatically redirect to #/hello, because of the routing configuration. It doesn't. Second, if you open directly [#/hello](https://angular-customelements-routing-ts7dyc.stackblitz.io/#/hello), then the route is not activated. Furthermore, any changes to URL are ignored. Only clicking directly on the link works

Comment: I think I got confused yesterday, I could have sworn it was working as expected! But I checked again today and indeed it did not work. I posted an answer that'll help you hopefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case of custom element, router.initialNavigation had to be called manually:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router,
    private location: Location) {
    const appElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('my-app', appElement);


  public ngDoBootstrap(): void {
    // workaround for bug - initial route not loaded: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23740
    this.router.initialNavigation();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working by following [this tutorial](http://chatwithme.io/angularjs%20upgrade/web%20components/angular%20elements/angular/angularjs/ngupgrade/2019/04/25/shipping-an-angular-application-as-a-web-component.html).

From what I understand, angular elements do not really support internal application routing (see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990501/angular-elements-router-outlet)) and this open [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23740).

The solution is to manually instruct the router to navigate to internal routes when the location changes

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router,
    private location: Location) {
    const appElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
   customElements.define('my-app', appElement);

    /**Add the lines below to your code**/
   //init router with starting path
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.location.path(true));

    //on every route change tell router to navigate to defined route
    this.location.subscribe(data => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(data.url);
    });
```

}

Here is the working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customelements-routing-y81vqs)

Comment: doesn't it create memory leak? In my case, the my-app custom elements is being dynamically added, resp removed from the DOM. The application is built and used as webcomponent

Comment: Unsubscribe from location when the element is removed from the dom?

Comment: Thanks for you help. I think that router.initialNavigation() is what I was looking for